# why adding a new Promise in the component result in `await act()` to fail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

below is the code:

```
function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
      );
      const { title } = await response.json();
      setTitle(title);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return <>{title}</>;
};

it("renders title", async () => {
   jest.spyOn(window, "fetch").mockResolvedValue({
      json: async () => ({ title: "Fetched" }),
   });

   await act(async () => {
      render(<App />);
   });

   expect(screen.getByText("Fetched")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

currently the test passes, but if I change the component by adding a new `Promise` as:

```
function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
      );
      const { title } = await response.json();
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));  // <------add this line fails the test
      setTitle(title); // this happens after the test is done
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return <>{title}</>;
};
```

so why adding a new Promise in the component result in the test failure?